# How to use sobel operator in C# using emgu cv?

Tags: c#, emgucv

i am feeling difficulty in applying sobel operator in c# using emguCv.
your kind comments would be quite valuable help for me in this regard.

here is the code::

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> imOriginal;
Image<Bgr, Byte> imgProcessed;
Image<Gray, Byte> imgProcessed1;
Image<Gray, Byte> imEdge;



imgProcessed = imgProcessed.SmoothGaussian(9);
imgProcessed1= imgProcessed.Convert<Gray,byte>();
imEdge = (imgProcessed1.Sobel(1, 0, 3));
```

Error   2

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`Emgu.CV.Image<emgu.cv.structure.gray,float>`' to
>   '`Emgu.CV.Image<emgu.cv.structure.gray,byte>`

thanx in advance.

regards 
baltee

Comment: Then post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: the sobel in EMGU works like gabbor filter :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image to float first and then apply Sobel.

```
Image<Gray, Single> img = imgProcessed1.Convert<Gray, Single>();
Image<Gray,Single>img_final = (img.Sobel(1, 0, 3));
```